# Does Undertow support async I/O from an async source?

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java, undertow, servlet-3.1

I have a scenario where I’m attempting to serve data in a non-blocking fashion which is sourced by a RxJava Observable (also non-blocking). I’m using the WriteListener callback provided by ServletOutputStream. I’m running into an issue where the write is throwing an IllegalStateException (`java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010035: Stream in async mode was not ready for IO operation`) immediately after a successful `isReady()` check on the ServletOutputStream.

While looking deeper, I noticed this comment in the Undertow implementation of [ServletOutputStream](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/servlet/src/main/java/io/undertow/servlet/spec/ServletOutputStreamImpl.java):

> Once the write listener has been set operations must only be invoked on this stream from the write listener callback. Attempting to invoke from a different thread will result in an IllegalStateException.

Given that my data source is asynchronous there are scenarios where the `onWritePossible()` callback will reach a state where there no data immediately available and I would need to wait for more to be received from the source. In these cases, I would need to interact with the stream from the callback of my data source which is going to be a different thread. The only other option would be to suspend the thread used to call `onWritePossible()` and wait for more data to arrive, but this would be a blocking operation which defeats the whole purpose.

Is there another approach that I’m missing? The single thread requirement of Undertow doesn’t seem to be required by the [Servlet 3.1](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html)   spec. From what I’ve read, other implementations appear to tolerate the multi-threaded approach given that the application coordinates the stream access synchronization.

Comment: Your question is about asynchronous I/O, not non-blocking. They aren't the same thing.

Comment: I would ask on the undertow-dev list, it looks indeed like a non compliant Serviet implementation (if it is part of undertow and not provided by wildfly)

Comment: @EJP Yes and no. I'm trying to achieve a non-blocking operation via a pair of asynchronous APIs. I do agree that your edit makes the question more clear so thank you for that.

Comment: @eckes Thanks. I actually tried to post this question to the undertow-dev list before posting here, but it was bounced back with a "permission denied" error. I was hoping some of the undertow devs might see this.